# Bigcommerce: Uninstall Callback URL

Tags: c#, bigcommerce

We´re trying to create a new app for the Bigcommerce app store. We´ve working the install callback url, but the load & uninstall callback seems like it´s not being triggered when clicking on the Uninstall button (or the app icon, for the load callback). We´ve added a log line at the very beginning of the uninstall method, but doesn´t writes anything, so it´s like it´s not being called. The URL is OK (https://www.example.com/UnInstall) and the method is something like this:

```
    public void UnInstall(string signed_payload)
    {
        Log.Instance.Write("Bigcommerce", "UnInstall", signed_payload);
    }
```

(this code is just a silly example to try to find out if the method is being triggered).

Am I missing something?

Thanks mates!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the issue is that you are using a local domain (not sure about that). But you need to use a public link in the uninstall callback, Maybe you get confused because the install callback can be a local one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ngrok to test endpoints because bigcommerce need to "see" you online.

Eg: `https://de93d105.ngrok.io/bigcommerce/uninstall`

also uninstall callback url need to match with the one in you app technical settings
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- **[Auth Callback](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/apps/guide/auth#receiving-the-get-request)**: loads in BigCommerce iframe
- **[Load Callback](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/apps/guide/callbacks#load-callback)**: loads in BigCommerce iframe
- **[Uninstall Callback](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/apps/guide/callbacks#uninstall-callback)**: loads BigCommerce from server-side

For **Auth** & **Load** callbacks you can use your local environment. But for **Uninstall** callback you have to use public url (own domain or [ngrok.io](https://ngrok.io/)).

By the way, no needs to return redirect or any other responses in **Uninstall** callback. There are no *views* for user there.